# Inputting User values in python dictionary from HTML Form field and showing Output in HTML page

Tags: html, python-3.x, forms, dictionary

I have a Python Script that at this point of time uses hard coded input values for calculating the algorithm .

```
from sys import stdin
from sys import stdout

capacity=13;
num_of_items=6;
total_weight=0;
total_value=0;

#Dictionary to store item numbers and corresponding weights
#<Item number, weight>

item_weight={0:4,1:2,2:3,3:1,4:7,5:10};

#Dictionary to store item numbers and corresponding values
#<Item number, value>

item_value={0:6,1:4,2:5,3:3,4:9,5:7};
```

I am not getting how to input the values from the text field .

So the inputted values will have `capacity , num_of_times, total_weight , total_value` from users AND `item_weight` and `item_value` as dictionary input from users.

Tried Yattag as suggested by some one but I cant get it to work around.

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use “flask” framework, this will enable HTTP requests from HTML

Comment: Yes , I am trying now to use CGI-bin for form data